# How to enrich message header based on message id in spring integration DSL?

Tags: java, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

My Integration floowlooks like this:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Http.inboundGateway("/spring_integration_post")
            .requestMapping(m -> m.methods(HttpMethod.POST))
            .requestPayloadType(String.class))
            .enrich(enricherSpec -> {
                enricherSpec.header("correlationId", 1); //or ackCorrelationId ?
            })
            .split(s -> s.applySequence(false).get().getT2().setDelimiters(","))
            .log()
            .log()
            .handle(Amqp.outboundAdapter(amqpTemplate())
                    .exchangeName("barrierExchange")
                    .routingKey("barrierKey"))
            .get();
}
```

As you can see I have enricher here:

```
.enrich(enricherSpec -> {
                    enricherSpec.header("correlationId", 1);
})
```

For now it adds header `correlationId` with constan value `1`. But I want to copy messageId (`id`) `correlationId`. I have no idea how can I achieve it using DSL.

I found working xml alternative:

```
  <int:header-enricher input-channel="receiveChannel" output-channel="processChannel">
        <int:header name="ackCorrelation" expression="headers['id']" />
    </int:header-enricher>
```

How can I do the same using java DSL ?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you read [the documentation - Configuring a Header Enricher with the Java DSL](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/#configuring-a-header-enricher-with-the-java-dsl) and javadocs instead of keep asking questions here. You will make much quicker progress.

We don't have time to keep answering trivial questions that are already covered by the documentation; our time would be better spent improving the framework.

Example from the documentation:

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow enrichHeadersInFlow() {
    return f -> f
                ...
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("emailUrl", this.emailUrl)
                                     .headerExpression("from", "payload.from[0].toString()"))
                .handle(...);
}
```

In your case `enricherSpec.headerExpression("ackCorrelation", "headers['id']")`

Comment: But how could I guess what could I write inside expression? Is it SPEL? Which magic objects are available there ? Is there more safe way to achieve  it ?

Comment: I really try to google how to achieve what I want but it really complex for me. Before asking the question I try to find a solution but It is not obvious for me yet. looks like I miss something important. But I started from package where you put readme file and wrote that it is a good place to start

Comment: Yes, the framework extensively uses SpEL - you should really try and read through the first 12 chapters of [the reference manual](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.1.7.RELEASE/reference/html/) to get a basic understanding of the concepts before digging to to converting XML samples to DSL. You will find SpEL is used throughout.